# Why isn't the product rule used to derive x = 2sin(t)

Tags: trigonometry, derived-functors

Since there is a multiplication occurring shouldn't the product rule be used? Or is the answer still dx/dt = 2cos(t) if the product rule is used? When I used the product rule I got 2cos(t) + sin(t).

Answer (score 5):

Since the derivative is a linear operator, we can pull the constant out and differentiate $sin(t)$. However if you do apply the product rule:$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=2\cos(t)+(0)\sin(t)=2\cos(t)$$ The zero is due to the derivative of a constant being $0$. It looks like you messed up and took the derivative of $2$ to be $1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: For trig functions use `\sin(t)` instead of `sin(t)`. The difference in math is $$\sin(t)\;\text{ vs }\;sin(t)$$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have not been a part of this community for too long so I have still to navigate among some of the MathJax used here.

Comment: You're fine. If you want one more hint, use roman characters for the `d` in differentials $$ \frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} \;\text{ vs }\;\frac{d x}{d t} $$ To get a roman `d` use `{\rm d}` or `\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: Will keep in mind for future use.